# Connection and setup of VL53L0X for STM32 microcontroller

Tags: c

I did not find more than one normal of the described example for connecting and working the VL53L0X with the STM32 microcontroller. All examples are tied to using the library from ST to work with VL53L0X. Is there any way to work with VL53L0X without using any libraries? Just send an inquiry via I2C and receive a response. Maybe someone faced such a problem and found a solution?

If it is necessary to use the library to work with VL53L0X, then someone can explain in detail how to use it on any microcontroller from ST, and not just with P-NUCLEO-53L0A1 as in the example from ST. In all my programs I use exclusively CMSIS, and not when I didn’t work with HAL libraries, so I don’t know how to connect this library?

Comment: read the STM32 "reference manual" where everything is described

Comment: @P__J__ What exactly is described?

Comment: As I wrote above, I did not find more than one example of using VL53L0X with the ST microcontroller. Only with test board P-NUCLEO-53L0A1

Answer (score 1):

Visit https://github.com/yetifrisstlama/vl53l0x-non-arduino

It is a lightweight VL53L0X API which does not use any HAL-Lib. You can easily implement it into your project.

Currently I am working on a Version of this API, including some HAL references for a better i2c communication. Maybe I will leave it here later when done.

Comment: Many thanks! I will study this API. Write if you get something new for VL53L0X. If something doesn't work for me, can I ask you a question here?

Comment: I connected the library, but I don’t understand how to work with it. Could you explain how to work with this library?

Comment: If you have specific questions about CMSIS, I can't help you because I haven't worked with it yet. For usage, there is an example in the report, which describes a simple integration. I think you have to change some parameters and change some of the used libraries for your use.